# Getting previous page visited

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, httprequest, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to get thee previous page visited in ASP.NET using VB.NET using the following code:

```
Partial Class _Default Inherits Page        
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim previousPage As String = Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString
        If (Request.UrlReferrer <> Nothing) Then
            If previousPage.Contains("Login") Then
                Dim tUsername As String = Session("Username")
                lblUsername.Text = "Welcome, " + tUsername
            ElseIf previousPage.Contains("Register") Then
                Dim cUsername As String = Session("CUsername")
                lblUsername.Text = "Welcome, " + cUsername
            Else
                lblUsername.Text = "Welcome, Guest"
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at:

```
Dim previousPage As String = Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString
```

What I want to do is get the previous page visited so I can get a session variable.

Comment: Well, checking Page.Request.UrlReferrer if it is not null, then proceed with your code? Page.Request.UrlReferrer may be null, check docs. Also, why you do not use HttpContext.Current.User.Name or similar instead saving it to Session?

Comment: What do you mean? I use that in the previous page?

Comment: Move `Dim previousPage As String = Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString`
 inside the `If (Request.UrlReferrer <> Nothing) Then` block. This would stop the null reference error.

Comment: thanks ! but the part where it should show 'Welcome, Guest' doesn't work i.e. if a new comer comes to the website, nothing will display.

Answer (score 1):

Try This code.

```
Partial Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            If (Request.UrlReferrer <> Nothing) Then

               Dim previousPage As String = Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString

                If previousPage.Contains("Login") Then

                    Dim tUsername As String = Session("Username")

                    lblUsername.Text = "Welcome, " + tUsername

                ElseIf previousPage.Contains("Register") Then

                    Dim cUsername As String = Session("CUsername")

                    lblUsername.Text = "Welcome, " + cUsername
                End If

            Else
                    lblUsername.Text = "Welcome, Guest"

            End If

        End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what you are trying to do but while its easy enough to answer your specific question, you should take a step back and review why you are doing things that way.

It *seems* you are trying to control flow based on some authentication. If so, consider [ASP.Net Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx) +/- Login Controls. You can "plug" this architecture into your existing auth mechanism (meaning you don't have to uproot your existing stuff to implement it).

(If you still want to reinvent the wheel) Consider cookies instead of trying to figure out *"where the user came from"* prior to landing on *"this"* page - both of which can vary by x - the more web pages your web site has or will have, you'll have more spaghetti.